# Ubuntu 16.04 Wifi not working

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently. I was unable to view the wifi networks available. I had to add my wifi explicitly and even then was unable to connect to it. I checked some answers in here and ran the following command:

sudo service network-manager restart

After this, I was able to connect to the wifi but it got disconnected within 2 minutes. Everytime I connect, it disconnects in 2 mins. And after the restart, it is unable to connect.

So again I ran the following steps:

1. Get details of your PCI wireless card by running sudo lshw -class network
2. Get your card model info according to the product line. For instance, as u can see in the question description it says product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter so the model of my card is RTL8723BE
3. Open or create /etc/pm/config.d/config and add SUSPEND_MODULES="rtl8723be"(replace rtl8723be with your own model number) Then run echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf and reboot.

But even after the restart, I am unable to connect.

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: 4.4.0-71-generic